# Caption - more lines align

Tags: captions

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{caption}
\setmainfont{Segoe UI}%
  [BoldFont=Segoe UI Bold]  
\usepackage[tablename=TABLE]{caption} 
\captionsetup{labelfont=bf}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\caption[]{fadafsd \\dasfsda \\adsfasd \\
    dasfsd}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{cr}
a&A
\end{tabular}    
\end{center}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

I have a caption in table split to more lines, how to align all parts below?

Comment: `\captionsetup{format=hang}`, if I understand well what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it what you want?

A small remark: don't use the `centre` environment with floats: it adds unwanted vertical spacing. Use `\centering` instead.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{caption}
\setmainfont{Segoe UI}%
  [BoldFont=Segoe UI Bold]
\usepackage[tablename=TABLE]{caption}
\captionsetup{labelfont=bf, format=hang}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\caption{Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah\\dasfsda \\adsfasd dasfsd\\
    dasfsd adsfasd fadafsd}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{cr}
a&A
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help